# getting the items about to expire 3 months from now in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

i'm currently doing my project and i dont know the code for getting the items that is about to expire 3 months from date today. anyone there who can help me about this? thanks

```
Function popCat()
    Call populateOnGrid(da, dset, _
      "Select * from tblItems where cdate(Expiry_Date)<>cdate('" & Date.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "') order by Category,Item_Name", "tblItems", dgExpiry)
    lblrecFnd.Text = totRec & " Records/s found"
    Call formatGrid()
    Return True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

`cdate(Expiry_Date)=cdate('" & Date.Today.AddMonths(3).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in SQL if you want:

```
Select * from tblItems where cdate(Expiry_Date) => DATEADD(month, 3, GETDATE())
```

This gives you all items which expire in 3 months or more. Or do you want only those which expire *exactly* in three months?

- [Documentation for DATEADD()](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms186819.aspx)
- [Documentation for GETDATE()](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188383.aspx)